El spinner no muestra los ítems
El combo-box (también llamado spinner) no muestra los ítems. Tengo un proyecto que también los usa y en ese aparecen, he revisado todos los hilos posibles tanto en inglés como en castellano tanto de este foro como de otros sitios, pero en ninguno encuentro la solución.
Decidí usar este spinner porque los RadioButton junto con el RadioGroup tampoco quisieron disparar los eventos de touch, click o Change.
Éste es el XML del fragment (es la 2da pestaña de un Tab, usa el ViewPager2):
layout_frg_sensors
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragment_Sensors">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_SnsrNmbr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_SnsrNmbr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Sensor number: "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"/>
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/CB_SnsrNmbr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_Samples"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/Div_Samples"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_Credentials"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Samples "
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_SmplFrq"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_SmplFrq"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Frequency "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/TF_SmplFrq"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_SmplFrq_ms"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="(milliseconds)"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_SmplType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_SmplType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Input type: "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"/>
            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/RG_SmplType"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/RB_SmplTp_Integer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Integer  "
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/RB_SmplTp_Float"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Floating"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_SmplTmSnd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_SmplTmSnd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Elapsed time  between sends "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/TF_SmplTmSnd"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_SmplTmSnd_secs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="(seconds)"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_ClbrtnFctr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_SmplClbrtnFctr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Calibration factor "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/TF_SmplClbrtnFctr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_HowToSend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/Div_HowToSend"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_HowToSend"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="How to send "
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_MethodToSend_CB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_Method"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Método: "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/CB_MethodToSend"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_TpcStrng"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_TpcStrng"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Topic string: "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/TF_TpcStrng"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_Alerts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/Div_Alerts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_Alerts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Alerts "
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/CK_Alerts_Enable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enable sending alerts "
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans"/>
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/TL_Alerts_values"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TR_Alerts_MinValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Lbl_Alerts_MinValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Min value "
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/TF_Alerts_MinValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TR_Alerts_MaxValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Lbl_Alerts_MaxValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Min value "
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/TF_Alerts_MaxValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </TableRow>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LL_Check"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/Div_Check"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Lbl_Check"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:text="Data input check "
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_CheckCurrentValue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Lbl_Check_CurrentValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Current value: "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/TF_Check_CurrentValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Btn_Check"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Read" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


Fragment_Sensors
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
//import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class Fragment_Sensors extends Fragment
{ MainActivity         MA;
  public Fragment_Sensors(MainActivity _MA)
  { this.MA=_MA;
  }
  public Fragment_Sensors()
  { this.MA=((MainActivity)this.getActivity());
  }
  public static Fragment_Sensors newInstance(String param1, String param2)
  { Fragment_Sensors fragment=new Fragment_Sensors();
    return fragment;
  }
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  { // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    { View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frg_sensors, container, false);
      { this.MA.CB_SnsrNmbr=view.findViewById(R.id.CB_SnsrNmbr);
        this.MA.AdapterSensors=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.MA, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.MA.Sensors);
        this.MA.AdapterSensors.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        this.MA.CB_SnsrNmbr.setAdapter(this.MA.AdapterSensors);
        this.MA.CB_SnsrNmbr.setOnItemSelectedListener(this.MA);
        this.MA.AdapterSensors.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.MA.CB_SnsrNmbr.setSelection(0);
      }
      { this.MA.CB_Method=view.findViewById(R.id.CB_MethodToSend);
        this.MA.AdapterMethods=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.MA, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.MA.MethodOptions);
        this.MA.AdapterMethods.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        this.MA.CB_Method.setAdapter(this.MA.AdapterMethods);
        this.MA.CB_Method.setOnItemSelectedListener(this.MA);
        this.MA.AdapterMethods.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.MA.CB_Method.setSelection(0);
      }
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frg_sensors, container, false);
  }
}


Y también el Main:
MainActivity
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
{ TabLayout        TabbedPage;
  ViewPager2       VP2;
  TabItem          Page_Config;
  TabItem          Page_Sensors;
  ViewStateAdapter VSA;
  Fragment         Frgmnts[];
  public volatile Spinner              CB_Method;
  public volatile Spinner              CB_SnsrNmbr;
  public          Spinner              CB_Devices;
  public volatile RadioButton          RB[];
  public volatile RadioGroup           RGL,RGR;
  public static   String               Sensors[]= new String[]{" 0"," 1"," 2"," 3"," 4"," 5"," 6"," 7"," 8"," 9",};
  public static   String               MethodOptions[]= new String[]{"  Average","  One by one","  Maximum","  Minimum","  All of the samples"};
  public static   String               DetectedDevices[]= new String[]{"  192.168.0.10-Vavle","  192.168.0.13-Presion","  192.168.0.18-Gate","  192.168.0.19-DownStairs"};
  public volatile ArrayAdapter<String> AdapterSensors;
  public volatile ArrayAdapter<String> AdapterMethods;
  public volatile ArrayAdapter<String> AdapterDevices;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.Frgmnts=new Fragment[]{new Fragment_Configuration(),new Fragment_Sensors(this)};
    { //ViewPager2+TabLayout
      TabbedPage=findViewById(R.id.TabbedPage);
      VP2=findViewById(R.id.Pager_0);
      Page_Config=findViewById(R.id.Page_Config);
      Page_Sensors=findViewById(R.id.Page_Sensors);
      VSA=new ViewStateAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),this.getLifecycle(),Frgmnts);
      VP2.setAdapter(VSA);
      TabbedPage.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
      VP2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback()
                                       { @Override
                                         public void onPageSelected(int position)
                                         { TabbedPage.selectTab(TabbedPage.getTabAt(position));
                                         }
                                       });
    }
    { this.CB_Devices=findViewById(R.id.CB_DetectedDevices);
      this.AdapterSensors=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.DetectedDevices);
      this.AdapterSensors.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      this.CB_Devices.setAdapter(this.AdapterDevices);
      this.CB_Devices.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
      //this.AdapterDevices.notifyDataSetChanged();
      this.CB_Devices.setSelection(0);
    }
  }
  @Override public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
  { VP2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    VSA.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
  @Override public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab){}
  @Override public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab){}
  @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  { /*if( parent==CB_Cnnctn_Zip)
       ((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).CBCnnctnZip_value=(byte)position;
     if( parent==CB_Cnnctn_Cnnctns)
       ((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).CBCnnctnCnnctns_value=(byte)position;*/
  }
  @Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}
}

Las propiedades y sus valores son los mismos que en el otro proyecto (el de llamadas por streaming), solo que allí funcionan tanto los ComboBox como los RadioButton, en este no.
Ignoro qué estoy haciendo mal o si es a causade alguna falla de Android Studio. Estoy usando allí Artic Fox y el emulador es Pixel API R_Android 11. En otra máquina tengo el LadyBug Patch 2 pero el emulador solo funcionó una vez y jamás se pudo volver a iniciar.
Por favor, si alguien puede ilustrarme sobre la falla le agradezco por su tiempo y disposición.
